# How to assign Redis key names to Flask app users?

Tags: python, flask, redis, flask-session

I have a Flask app which stores user sessions in Redis on localhost.
User sessions are managed by Flask-Session module:

```
import flask
import redis  
import flask_session

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = b'Test123'

app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'redis'
app.config['SESSION_KEY_PREFIX'] = 'flask_session_'
app.config['SESSION_PERMANENT'] = False
app.config['SESSION_USE_SIGNER'] = True
app.config['SESSION_REDIS'] = redis.from_url('redis://localhost:6379', password='Test123')

server_session = flask_session.Session(app)
```

I'd like to know which Redis session key **name** belongs to which user or device.
For example I'd like to add client's IP addresses to Redis key names.
Is it possible?
When I try to get client's IP address and set it as a key prefix like this:

```
ip = flask.request.environ.get('REMOTE_ADDR')

app.config['SESSION_KEY_PREFIX'] = 'flask_session_' + ip
```

I get this message in Apache error.log:

> RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.
> [Fri Feb 11 22:19:14.371919 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 264638:tid 264787] [remote 1.2.3.4:35695] This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
> [Fri Feb 11 22:19:14.371930 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 264638:tid 264787] [remote 1.2.3.4:35695] an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
> [Fri Feb 11 22:19:14.371941 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 264638:tid 264787] [remote 1.2.3.4:35695] information about how to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out.
Obviously you can't run  `flask.request.environ.get('REMOTE_ADDR')` before the request, even with `@app.before_request`.
So, to identify sessions (Redis key names) and assign them to app users (so I know which session/key belongs to which user) my app now writes Flask-Session SID along with the logged in username to the Apache error.log:

```
app.logger.warning('User ' + login + ' logged in. Flask-Session SID: ' + str(flask.session.sid) + '. Flask-Login session ID: ' + str(flask.session['_id']) + '.')
```

Flask-Session SID is the Redis key name.
Another way would be storing the username or IP address in flask.session after the request (after the users login), `SCAN`-ning the Redis `KEYS` for values (usernames or IP address) and `RENAME`-ing the keys by pattern.